# Tastypie resource not showing newly created objects (date filtering issue)

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a model with a custom manager with the purpose of filtering "active" objects, i.e. objects which have a `start_date` lower than the current time and an `end_date` greater than the current time.

This is the relevant part of my `models.py`:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class ActiveObjectManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveObjectManager, self).get_query_set().\
            filter(start_date__lt=now(), end_date__gt=now())

class Object(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Service start date'), \
        auto_now_add=False, null=False, blank=False)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Service end date'), auto_now_add=False, \
        null=False, blank=False)
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
    objects_active = ActiveObjectManager()
```

This manager works great across the application and in a Django shell. However, if I create an object in the admin interface, and set the `start_date` to the "now" selector, the API provided by tastypie isn't showing this newly created object (though it does show older objects). The admin list correctly shows the new object as active.

This is the relevant part of my `api.py`:

```
from app.models import Object

class ActiveObjectResource(ModelResource):
    modified = fields.BooleanField(readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'activeobjects'
        queryset = Object.objects_active.all()
```

My strong suspicion is that, as the class `ActiveObjectResource` is being interpreted once,  the couple of `now()` calls are only being executed once, i.e., the API subsystem is always calling `filter()` with the same values for the `start_date__lt` and `end_date__gt` parameters (the value returned by `now()` immediately after I run `manage.py runserver`).

This problem persists even when I do the filtering right in the resource class like this:

```
class ActiveObjectResource(ModelResource):
    ...
    class Meta:
        queryset = Object.objects.\
            filter(start_date__lt=now(), end_date__gt=now())
```

Also, the problem persists if I pass callables like this:

```
class ActiveObjectResource(ModelResource):
    ...
    class Meta:
        queryset = Object.objects.filter(start_date__lt=now, end_date__gt=now)
```

Is there a way I can rewrite `ActiveObjectManager` or `ActiveObjectResource` to overcome this?

**Update:**
OK, it seems I need to override `get_object_list` to achieve [per-request alterations to the queryset](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset), like:

```
class ActiveObjectResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Object.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(MyResource, self).get_object_list(request).\
            filter(start_date__lt=now, end_date__gt=now)
```

But I hate to duplicate this logic when I already have a custom manager at the model level to do this work for me.

So my question is: **how can I use my custom model manager from within my `ModelResource`?**

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, because I'm not 100% sure about this. Still, my guess is that since calling `Object.active_objects.all()` multiple times is still *technically* the same queryset, query caching is coming into play. Meanwhile, `Object.objects.filter(...)` is obviously a different query on its surface, and thus invalidates the query cache each time it's called.

Comment: @ChrisPratt No, multiple calls to `Object.active_objects.all()` produce different querysets, by virtue of what's defined in `get_query_set`, and demonstrated by the fact that manually calling that manager in a shell is working as expected. The problem is that `Object.active_objects.all()` is called _only once_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, about queryset in `ModelResource.Meta`. Here's the [excerpt from the tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#queryset):

> If you place any callables in this, they’ll only be evaluated once (when the Meta class is instantiated). This especially affects things that are date/time related. Please see the :ref:cookbook for a way around this.

Here [it goes](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset):

> A common pattern is needing to limit a queryset by something that changes per-request, **for instance the date/time**. You can accomplish this by lightly modifying get_object_list

So, yeah, seems like the only way to achieve what you are trying to do is to declare `get_object_list`.

**New Update:** since `get_object_list` is just a `return self._meta.queryset._clone()`, try something like that:

```
class ActiveObjectResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Object.objects_active.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return Object.objects_active.all()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what I ended up doing, sort of. I'm doing this: `self._meta.queryset = NewsGroup.objects_active.all(); return super(NewsGroupAssignationResource, self).get_object_list(request)`. Which is a bit hacky (the `Meta.queryset` value is completely useless), but gets the job done.